# Crystal Reports - Adding a QR Code in invoice report

Tags: c#, qr-code

I have an accounting program web work by iis  ASPX c#,
How do I enable billing feature with QR code in Crystal Report ASP
we use vs 2013, sql 2014

thank

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could use LEADTOOLS. (Free evaluation [here](https://www.leadtools.com/downloads)). First create an empty image with Leadtools.RasterImage.Create() then write the QR code using BarcodeEngine.Writer.WriteBarcode(). Finally save it as image using Leadtools.Codecs.RasterCodecs.Save(). To include the barcode images into the Crystal report, [see this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LXCzSqck1Pw). For more details, see the [Write Barcodes tutorial](https://leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/tutorials/dotnet-console-write-1d-and-2d-barcodes-to-an-image.html). Disclosure: I work for LEADTOOLS vendor